Add a column with a foreign key to an existing table?
I use Microsoft SQL Server and I have this table in the database:
+-------------------------------+
|           MEASURE             |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| id | measure | units  | value |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| 1  | linear  | meters | 100   |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| 2  | linear  | inches | 24    |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| 3  | linear  | inches | 32    |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| 4  | linear  | meters | 70    |
+----+---------+--------+-------+

I created a new table:
+-------------+
|     UNIT    |
+----+--------+
| id | units  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | meters |
+----+--------+
| 2  | inches | 
+----+--------+

Now, I want to create a relationship between these tables. My desired result is something like this:
+-------------------------------+
|           MEASURE             |
+----+---------+--------+-------+                    +-------------+
| id | measure | units  | value |                    |     UNIT    |
+----+---------+--------+-------+                    +----+--------+
| 1  | linear  | 1      | 100   | >----------------o | id | units  |
+----+---------+--------+-------+                    +----+--------+
| 2  | linear  | 2      | 24    |                    | 1  | meters |
+----+---------+--------+-------+                    +----+--------+
| 3  | linear  | 2      | 32    |                    | 2  | inches |
+----+---------+--------+-------+                    +----+--------+
| 4  | linear  | 1      | 70    |
+----+---------+--------+-------+

How to add a column with a foreign key to an existing table so that it refers to the appropriate unit(ID) values?

Why do you feel this needs a surrogate key? The units column is narrow enough to be a primary and foreign key by itself.

@Charlieface is there any point having a second table in that case?

@DaleK Yes of course, to enforce the FK relationship, only values in that PK can be in the FK column. This is a typical design of an enum table in databases which do not have such a feature. So I would suggest just create a single column table wth FK CREATE TABLE unit (unit varchar(8) PRIMARY KEY); INSERT ..... ALTER TABLE measure ADD CONSTRAINT FK_unit FOREIGN KEY (units) REFERENCES unit (unit); you might want to add a plural and non-plural name also.

@DaleK That's not answering the question though. It's a comment explaining why the question might be an XY problem.

Step 1: Add a new column UnitsFK creating a FK relationship to the Unit table
ALTER TABLE Measure ADD UnitsFK INT FOREIGN KEY (UnitsFK) REFERENCES Unit(id);

Step 2: Populate the new column
UPDATE Measure SET UnitsFK = (SELECT id FROM Unit u WHERE u.Units = Measure.Units);

Step 3: Drop the old Units column
ALTER TABLE Measure DROP COLUMN Units;

Step 4: Rename the new UnitsFK column to Units
EXEC sp_rename 'Measure.UnitsFK', 'Units', 'COLUMN';


Firstly you need to rename the column units in measure. Here is how to do it:
exec sp_rename 'Measure.units', 'unitsNames', 'column'

Here is a link for the documentation of the code -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-columns-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16
Here is a quick explanation of the code:
exec is used to execute a procedure. In this situation we use the procedure sp_rename, which is a system stored procedure. After that we have the name of the table and the column name that we want to change, followed by the new name that we want and finally we specify that we are changing a column.
After that you need to add another column, which you will populate afterwards. Here is how to do it:
alter table Measure
add unitsId int

Here is a link to the documentation -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/add-columns-to-a-table-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16
Explanation of the scrip:
alter table is used to make changes to a specified table.
add unitsId int is used to add a new column with the name
unitsId. The reason I changed the name from units to the new one is because it is a good practice to name the columns in such way if they are primary keys connected to another columns that are
Id columns. int is used to specify that the values in the columns would be integers.
After that you need to populate the column. Here is how to do it:
update m
set m.unitsId = u.ID
from measure as m
join Units as u on m.unitsNames = u.units

Here is a link to the explanation of how to use updates with joins -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
And here is a link to what aliases are(in your situation the Alias a table section) ->
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/aliases-sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver16
Explanation of the script:
update is used to make a change to the specified table
m is an alias to the table measure. Aliases are used for better readability in sql
set is used to change a certain column value or values to some value. In the example we are setting unitsId of measure to Id of units. By using the aliases m and u, we specify from which tables are the columns.
from is used to choose which table are we taking values from.
as is used to name the alias of the table.
join is used to combine the 2 tables on specific columns. In the script we combine on the measure unitsName column and the units units column.
Then you need to drop the column unitsNames since we don't need it anymore and you don't want it in you example results:
alter table Measure
drop column unitsNames

Quick explanation:
drop column - deletes a column from a table.
In order for your logic to work, you need to create a foreign key in the table Measure that connects the appropriate Measure column, with the right Unit column. In the example the column unitsId in Measure would be a perfect foreign key. You need to connect it through it and the ID column in the table Unit. Since you've already created the tables and you have the needed columns, all you need to do is alter the table where you need the foreign key created(in table Measure) and create the key. Here is an example of how to do it:
alter table Measure
add constraint fk_measureUnit foreign key (units) References Unit(ID)

Here is a link to the documentation of how to add fk at the creation of the table or afterwards -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver16
Here is an explanation of what each part of the script does:
add constraint is used to add a constraint(in this usage a foreign key). Other examples of constraints are the primary key, which is used to make sure that each row in the table is unique(for example in your table Unit the column Id would be perfect for it) and the unique constraint, which is used to make sure that each value in a column is different to the rest.
fk_measureUnit is the part where you name your foreign key. You can choose whatever name, but it's a good practice to start it with fk_ because that way you signalize to other developers what it is.
foreign key is used to specify what constraint you want to add to the table.
(units) is used to specify which column is going to be the foreign key.
References is used to tell which column from the second table is going to be connected to the first table, that has the fk. And after it you put the name of the table and in bracets the column you want to be used as a connection(in your example that would look like -> Unit(ID))

Smells very much like ChatGPT (which is banned) and, surprise, doesn't answer the question!

I don't know how it smells of chatGPT but I agree that it didn't answer the question. Which is why I instantly started edditing it.

Because thats not how normal people write. Many of the phrases used are identical to other ChatGPT answers. And it has far too much detail, refer the reader to the documentation for how it works. When I compare the writing style of this answer with your older answers, its completely different. So yip, its ChatGPT.

Ok. I usually write like that. Will add more documentation to the explanation of the code. I don't see what I can do if the code is similar to what other chatGPT answers would say? How can I change that especially in such questions where the answers are basic drop column, alter table and so on?

You don't normally write like that at all... I checked your earlier answers. So you already know how to answer in your own words. Complete giveaway, no one is ever going to write exec is used to execute a procedure.

So I shouldn't explain in such a way? How would you recommend I explain stuff in the future apart from the links?

Whether or not it's GPT: don't link W3Schools, they don't know what they're talking about half the time, and full of bad practices. The actual docs are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/?view=sql-server-ver16
